# Let $A \subset X$ with $X = cl(A)$ and $A$ connected, then the whole space $X$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I found this problem, but I solved it without $cl(A) = X$. I have the answer, it uses that fact. But I need to know what went wrong in my proof

Basically assume $X$ is separated $X = U \cup V$. Then $A = A \cap X = (A \cap U) \cup (A \cap V)$.

The sets $(A \cap U)$ and $(A \cap V)$ are clearly disjoint and open in A. So $A$ is separated, a contradiction.

Comment: Are both $A\cap U$ and $A\cap V$ nonempty?

Comment: I guess they could be....which might make this not work...

Comment: What about your missing hypothesis? What does it say?

Comment: Nothing about whether it is empty or not, so I guess there is the flaw.

Comment: You can prove that $cl(A)=X$ iff every nonempty open set of $X$ instersects $A$. Then you got the full argument. (If you assume $X$ is separated, then $U$ and $V$ should be nonempty open sets)

Comment: Well that is one of the characterization of closure. Actually the proof I am reading focuses on taking care of the case when they are empty...

Answer (score 1):

Anothet approach is to use the theorem that A is connected iff
for all continuous f:A -> {0,1} with the discrete topology, f is constant.
To prove your problem and the generalization:
connected A and A subset B subset $\bar A$ implies B is connected,
one can use the above theorem and the fact that for continuous f,
f($\bar A$) subset $\overline {f(A)}$.